# jQuery UI tooltips appearing when hovering over third-party ads

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

## Problem

I'm having an issue with tooltips with jQuery UI involving third-party ads. When I hover over the ad, I see a tooltip with the text "3rd party content". I only want the tooltips to appear on elements that have a class of `.fa-question-circle`

- I can see that the ad is being loaded through an iframe and it contains `title=3rd party ad content`. I just want to be able to prevent that from being seen by the user.

### scripts.js

```
  // Tooltips
  $(".fa-question-circle").tooltip({
    tooltipClass: "popup",
    position: {
      my: "center bottom-15",
      at: "center top"
    },
    hide: false
  });
```

Comment: Your 3rd party content should be rendering within your `$(".fa-question-circle")` element or the hover bubbling up...  Use [items:](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content) to specify the elements to apply the tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In the end, it looked like this:**

```
  // Tooltips
  $(document).tooltip({
    tooltipClass: "popup",
    items: ".fa-question-circle",
    position: {
      my: "center bottom-15",
      at: "center top",
      collision: 'none'
    },
    hide: false
  });
```